# Linux C: Using fork() child to change directory

Tags: c, linux, fork, children

I'm making a command shell where I'm using the child to change the directory of shell, but I can't get it to change an array's contents;

In the end it just prints the current directory instead of "/". The child has no effect on the newDirectory array. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to make the child change the contents of the array? Thanks.

```
char newDirectory[255];

getcwd(newDirectory, 255); //set newDirectory to current directory

pid_t pid;      

pid = fork();

if(pid == 0){   //child execution       

    strcpy(newDirectory, "/");

    exit(0);
}

else if (pid < 0){                  
    printf( "Error!\n");    
    exit(1);
}
else{                       
     pid = waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);   
}
printf("%s\n", newDirectory);
chdir(newDirectory);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(moving from the comment)*

When you do a `fork()` the new process is an *independent copy*<sup>1</sup> of the parent, so whatever change you make to variables of the child isn't visible from the parent process - they have two independent virtual address spaces.

If you want the child process to communicate with the parent you have to use some IPC method (e.g. pipes, shared memory, sockets, ...).

---

1. actually, on modern systems address space copying is actually implemented with copy on write, but that doesn't change the point.

Comment: Ah Thanks, I see. I thought using an array or pointer would be pointing to some shared memory between the processes. So that means the child does  a deep copy of everything, but uses the same names?

Comment: The fork does a blind copy of the whole virtual address space (including the data and the code segments), the file descriptors, ..., so yes, you can consider it a deep copy. By the way, the variable names are just a compile-time concept - after the compilation they are gone, all that remains are memory addresses (which are duplicated in the new process).

Comment: And each process has its own current directory, so `chdir(2)`-ing in one don't affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is not not use a child process to change the current working directory (because the current working directory will only change in the child process, not the parent, as stated by Matteo).

If you check existing shells (like `bash` or even `sh`) you will notice that some commands are considered "built-in" and `cd` is one such command.